# Permissions not available in Rally for items shown from child projects

Tags: permissions, rally

Given:

- Project A is the parent of Project B
- The context for the user is set to Project A (top-left dropdown)
- The user has Viewer access to Project A
- The user has Editor access to Project B

The user is unable to Add a Child to a User Story that belongs to Project B via the Plan > User Stories view (or any other view).

However, this issue was resolved when the user changed the context from Project A to Project B.

It appears as though the user must select a specific child project as the context, rather than work from the parent project level (for a full view), so that the user interface provides them with the correct permissions (i.e. sub-project permissions aren’t available in the user interface when the context is set to a parent project with fewer permissions).

Question: Is this the expected behaviour?

Tim.

Answer (score 1):

Tim,

Rally uses StackOverflow for technical questions about coding to Rally Software's various APIs including the App SDK, Ruby & .NET APIs, and Web Service API not as much for questions about our product.

That said, what you are seeing is probably the expected behavior based on our project-permission model. But it is a bit odd. If you would like more clarification, please click on 'contact support' at the bottom of any page in Rally and our support group will help investigate further.

-Mark